# Is it possible to use ojdbc7.jar with JDK8?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a program that requires the use of the Oracle JDBC connector. Recently however all the machines here have been upgraded too Java JDK 1.8.

I'm getting the following error when I try and use the file `ojdbc7.jar` by calling one of the methods.

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:;Rest of connection details here`

I am using the following three lines to access my database object:

```
//Create new connection to database
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

My stack trace is telling me that I am getting an error on the stmt line but I am getting no compilation errors.

I am wondering if either I am using the connector wrong (as I was originally using `ojdbc6.jar` but upgraded to see if the latest version would work or if the old version is incompatible?

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007. What's the URL you're connecting to? It looks like you're actually using a `jdbc:odbc` URl, which is no longer supported in Java 8.

Comment: I agree with EJP. Even in earlier versions you should not have used the ODBC bridge. It's buggy and slow as hell.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, the software I am interfacing with can only be accessed via an ODBC driver. As it appears it is no longer supported in Java 8 I may either need to hold back updates or write something new.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below syntax for getting a new connection.

```
// Create an OracleDataSource instance and set properties
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setUser("USER");
ods.setPassword("PASSWORD");
ods.setURL("URL");

   // New auto closable syntax applicable to connection. This syntax will
// close the connection automatically
try (OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) (ods.getConnection())) { 
...}
```

Also, check the below JDBC FAQ for compatibility question. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02

Answer (score -1):

Use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` as `oracle.jdbc.driver.*` are deprecated